# data templates wp7/8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a list of items and the items consist of multiple lines of information - I was using a listbox and used the itemtemplate to add a button and set the contents of the button as the multiple lines of text using a data template but it did not work - only 2 lines showed.Now, I am doing the same thing except I am not using the button and I cannot get the lines of text to go on the next line...

**Example:**

(didn't format correctly here - but each on a new line)
*Direction\n
TimePoint\n
Adherence*

**Currently its doing:**
(no new lines)
DirectionTimePointAdherence

**Here is the xaml...the binding is done in the code behind**

```
 <ListBox Name="listBox_1"  Background="Transparent" Margin="0,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="28" Foreground="#FF348F8F" Text="{Binding Direction}" Height="40"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="28" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TimePoint}" Height="40"/>
                                    <Grid Background="#FFE3EFFF">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="40" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="28" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Adherence}" Height="40"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your text. it might do the trick :

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: that didnt work either - still all showing up on the same line

Comment: i think you should remove the stackpanel orientation and put all your elements inside the grid. listbox itemtemplates should have stackpanel in vertical orientation